# How to fix clone problems

Tags: windows-vista, performance, clone, ghost

I recently cloned (using Ghost 15.0) my 200gb C drive to 500gb Z(in a USB attached enclosure). After the clone successfully? ended, I did have 2 duplicate drives. After removing power and battery, I swapped out the old C with the new Z. Booted in safe mode, ran Task mgr, and ran Regedit. In it I changed old C to a Q drive, and then changed Z to the C drive. I turned off machine and rebooted... seemingly successful. It found the new C and all was right with the world.

**Problems:**

- Email won't start unless, the Q drive (old C) is attached. (I was hoping to re-format the Q and use it in the external enclosure as additional hard drive space.)
- There is no indexing of the new drive, and everything runs... slowly.
- I was looking for a place to re-install Windows Mail, (came with the
  Vista OS), but found out that that was a no-no.

**My computer is:**

- HP Pavilion DV 6500
- SP1 and SP2 applied to Windows Vista
- Dual Core Intel chips 1GB each

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you went into the registry to change drive letters. . .

What you should of done was go into BIOS Setup and have your new drive as the startup drive.

In general, Windows assigns drive letter `C` to the startup drive, no matter what.

Comment: I agree, I would remake the clone, remove the original and place the clone in the original drive's boot order and boot from it, everything should work fine. No need to regedit paths or anything like that.